# Python-Issue writing to CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I can print results to terminal but unable to write to csv file

full file:https://1drv.ms/u/s!AizscpxS0QM4hJo5SnYOHAcjng-jww

```
 datapath = '1.json'

data = json.load(open(datapath))

with open('1.json') as file:
  data = json.load(file)

for element in data['RoleDetailList']:
 if 'RoleName' in element.keys():
   s = element['RoleName']
       #print s

 with open('roleassign.csv', 'wt') as file:
  file.write('Role,Policy\n')
  for policy in element['AttachedManagedPolicies']:
    c = s + ',' + policy['PolicyName']
    #print c
    file.write(c + '\n')
```

In csv file i get only headers, when uncomment `print c` i see lines are printed into terminal (output)

some of the lines from output:

```
ADFS-amtest-ro,pol-amtest-ro
adfs-host-role,pol-amtest-ro
aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role,AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
```

Comment: can u post sample json file

Comment: @RehanAzher posted in question, thanks

Comment: your `with` is indented 1 space putting it inside the `for element in data['RoleDetailList']:`. So, you rewrite the entire file each time. It turns out that on the last write, there isn't a policy element. I don't know what your intent is with the code, but you should either dedent the `with open` or open the file before you process the input.

Comment: btw, always use 4 spaces for indent. It was hard to spot your nesting because of the 1 space indent. Do it the same way as everybody else so its instantly familiar to everybody else.

Comment: I don't see how the answer you accepted fixed your problem. You keep overwriting the file on each iteration of `for element in data['RoleDetailList']:` . Using csv.writer doesn't fix that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer) from the csv built-in module

in your example:

```
with open('roleassign.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
  writer.writerow(['Role','Policy'])
  for policy in element['AttachedManagedPolicies']:
    c = [s, policy['PolicyName']]
    writer.writerow(c)
```

Additionally, to incorporate Rehan's answer, the loop that is updating you `s` variable shouldn't be out there. The code blow should work for you:

```
with open('roleassign.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
  writer.writerow(['Role','Policy'])
  for element in data['RoleDetailList']:
    if 'RoleName' in element.keys():
        s = element['RoleName']
    for policy in element['AttachedManagedPolicies']:
      c = [s, policy['PolicyName']]
      writer.writerow(c)
```

Comment: the writer can be handy if you want to have internal separator characters escaped but its not mandatory and it doesn't explain OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please try code below:

```
with open('output.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
with open('roleassign.csv', 'wt') as file:
    file.write('Role,Policy\n')
    for element in data['RoleDetailList']:
        if 'RoleName' in element.keys():
            s= element['RoleName']
        for policy in element['AttachedManagedPolicies']:
            c = s + ',' + policy['PolicyName']
            file.write(c + '\n')
```

Your File writer is being opened in the loop and every time it was overwriting the file with only the headers.  Simply moved it out.

Comment: Cheers no worries :) Glad it helped , Yes i Liked the above solution as well.

Comment: @milister - don't accept the one that didn't answer your question! If others see it later, they will be mighty confused.